# What is `require` in the content of Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is an extract of the Backbone.js source (near the very top):

```
// Require Underscore, if we're on the server, and it's not already present.   
var _ = root._;
if (!_ && (typeof require !== 'undefined')) _ = require('underscore')._;
```

At no point is `require` defined. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words Backbone.js can be used with non-browser JavaScript backend languages that follow the CommonJS spec like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Here's the bit about [require](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#loading_from_the_require.paths_Folders) in Node.js docs.

Answer (score 2):

It's checking for the presence of `require` from the CommonJS module specification. It's saying that if the global object doesn't contain `_`, try to require the `underscore` module (if `require` is defined) and get `_` from there.